# Firebase user control

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there any way to deny some part of an App to a specific user using Firebase?

The flow is as follow :

User X is authenticated and fill some field in the app and have his/her state on pending.

Firebase admin receive the data input from the end user, validate it and release the account so He/she can have access to the remaining part of the App.

I have been working on this the whole day. Hope someone help.I am kind of new to firebase.